# How to run this pandas for loop more faster using iterrows & iteritems

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, iteration

I have a for loop :

```
for j  in range(0,len(df)):
    for i in range(0,32):
        df.iloc[j,i] = df['split'].iloc[j][i]
```

This is taking more time to run. How to optimize it using some iteritems or iterrows or apply?

(I have dynamic number of rows and columns)

Sample:

```
   A  B  split
0  we    [w,e]
1  xy    [x,y]
2  ad    [a,d]
3  cf    [c,f]
4  de    [d,e]
5  tt    [t,t]
```

should become :

```
   A  B  split
0  w  e   [w,e]
1  x  y   [x,y]
2  a  d   [a,d]
3  c  c   [c,f]
4  d  e   [d,e]
5  t  t   [t,t]
```

Comment: provide sample input and expected output. It will make easy to try for an answer

Comment: input is provided

Comment: Please don't change your question after 3 answers. Get it right first time. But, if you don't, try and adapt the below solutions. If you're still stuck, after a few hours and the necessary research, feel free to post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
res= df['A'].apply(lambda x:pd.Series(list(x)))
out=pd.concat([df,res],axis=1)
```

`res` will contains new dataframe which is splitted by character. then merge with your old dataframe. rename the columns as your wish. It will work even dynamic range of characters.

**What will happend if i have seperator?**

just slight modification required,

```
res= df['A'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

Input:

```
     A  split
0  wez  [w,e]
1   xy  [x,y]
2   ad  [a,d]
3   cf  [c,f]
4   de  [d,e]
5   tt  [t,t]
```

Output:

```
     A  split  0  1    2
0  wez  [w,e]  w  e    z
1   xy  [x,y]  x  y  NaN
2   ad  [a,d]  a  d  NaN
3   cf  [c,f]  c  f  NaN
4   de  [d,e]  d  e  NaN
5   tt  [t,t]  t  t  NaN
```

Comment: I suggest you to don't add columns initially, because as you said it's dynamic you can't predict number of columns instead of that after `concat` operation try to rename it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using NumPy respresentation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['we', 'xy', 'ad', 'cf', 'de', 'tt'],
                   'B': ['', '', '', '', '', ''],
                   'split': [['w', 'e'], ['x', 'y'], ['a', 'd'],
                             ['c', 'f'], ['d', 'e'], ['t', 't']]})

df[['A', 'B']] = df['split'].values.tolist()

print(df)

   A  B   split
0  w  e  [w, e]
1  x  y  [x, y]
2  a  d  [a, d]
3  c  f  [c, f]
4  d  e  [d, e]
5  t  t  [t, t]
```

Here's another way using `str` accessor and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

df['A'] = df['A'].str[0]
df['B'] = df['split'].apply(itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: i have dynamic number of columns

Comment: @qwww, See update for a more extendible version. You can just specify `list('ABCDEFG')` instead of `['A', 'B', ....]` for 7 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another dynamic solution:

source DF:

```
In [272]: df
Out[272]:
        text
0  w;e;z;d;c
1      a;b;c
2          x
```

Solution:

```
In [273]: import string

In [274]: res = df['text'].str.split(';', expand=True).fillna('')

In [275]: res
Out[275]:
   0  1  2  3  4
0  w  e  z  d  c
1  a  b  c
2  x
```

rename columns if you don't like numeric column names:

```
In [276]: res = res.rename(columns=lambda c: string.ascii_uppercase[c])

In [277]: res
Out[277]:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  w  e  z  d  c
1  a  b  c
2  x
```

PS as @Mohamed Thasin ah has already mentioned, it doesn't make much sense to create empty columns beforehand.